# How to handle parallel make invocations with multiple ordered goals

Tags: makefile, gnu-make

GNU make allows 1) parallel execution and 2) specifying several goals in the same invocation:

```
make -j4 clean all
```

But, as GNU make parallelizes the goals, some race conditions can occur. Illustration:

```
$ cat Makefile
clean:
    @sleep 1 && rm -f foo

all: foo
    @sleep 2 && cat foo

foo:
    @echo '$@' > $@
$ make -j4 clean ; make -j4 all
foo
$ make -j4 clean all
cat: foo: No such file or directory
Makefile:5: recipe for target 'all' failed
make: *** [all] Error 1
```

Is there a nice way to force an order between the goals, but still benefit from the parallel acceleration for each goal? In the above example it would be nice to wait until `clean` completes before `all` starts in order to avoid race conditions.

As shown, the separate make invocations work as expected but this is not 100% satisfactory:

1. Some goals can be invoked simultaneously, some others cannot. Completely forbidding multiple goals can thus be considered as too restrictive. But identifying all valid and invalid combinations is tricky and error prone.
2. To completely avoid the problem, one could warn all potential users of such a Makefile that multiple goals invocations are not supported in parallel mode, but this warning will inevitably be overlooked by some users.
3. Race conditions do not always cause errors. Some could apparently work seamlessly but produce erroneous results.

Comment: Maybe you could just call `make clean && make all -j4` ? Or have a special `rebuild` target that has both `clean` and `all` as prerequisites, in this order. I'm not aware of other solutions.

Comment: @TimF Unfortunately, your `rebuild` target does not solve the problem. In my simple example you still get an error when invoking `make -j4 rebuild`. And the separate make invocations is an option (as shown in my original question) but I am looking for something better than instructing any potential user of my Makefiles that multiple goals invocations are not supported...

Comment: Well then I'd be curious to see if someone has another solution because I tried on my build setup and I have the same issue. But I really doubt there's a solution. By the way I also distribute a Makefile to a set of users and they always (intuitively) make `clean` and `all` in two separate commands, so in my case it's not a problem.

Comment: @RenaudPacalet my GNUmake fails even when I make `clean` a prerequisite to `all`, as it may assume that the DAG starting at foo will not interfere with the DAG of clean, which it does due to the invisible dependency over the file system.

Comment: @Vroomfondel Yes, having `clean` as a prerequisite of `all` does not solve the problem. And, anyway, even if it was working it would really be overkill: everything would have to be re-build every time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

IMHO this seems to root in the problem that in a programming language (in this case the shell) we are able to formulate dependencies which are of fundamentally different nature than the ones that make can handle. In your example there is a dependency of `clean` on the *non-existence* of `foo`, while `all` has the inverse dependency. If you make both targets active at the same time, this seems to surpass make's theoretical foundation - I don't know if there exists a sensible theory that can handle such relations. All that I could come up with is the explicit formulation:

```
.PHONY: all clean

clean:
    @sleep 1
    rm -f foo

all: foo $(filter clean,$(MAKECMDGOALS))
    @sleep 2
    cat foo

foo: $(filter clean,$(MAKECMDGOALS))
    @echo Creating $@
    @echo '$@' > $@
```

I think this is an interesting problem for sure.

Comment: Yes, I also tried to use `MAKECMDGOALS`. But your use of it looks better than mine. Thanks for this nice idea. We can even improve it a bit with one single extra rule: `all foo: $(filter clean,$(MAKECMDGOALS))` and all the others unchanged.

Comment: Nice hack, too bad it doesn't rely on a native GNU make feature because it becomes OS-dependant (and something as simple as natively waiting 2ms in a Unix environment becomes a pain in a Windows environment)

Comment: @TimF uhh... I think you missed my and Renauds point. This script acts just as demonstrator for the problem of dependency-contradictions. The `sleep` is just a placeholder for "any processing that causes a race condition between parallel threads evaluating contradicting dependency trees".

Answer (score 0):

I found a workaround (but I am not 100% convinced that it is the best solution and that it has no hidden drawbacks). The idea is to use the `MAKECMDGOALS` GNU make variable and the conditionals to force the serialization of multiple goals:

```
ifeq ($(words $(MAKECMDGOALS)),1)
.PHONY: all clean

clean:
    @sleep 1 && rm -f foo

all: foo
    @sleep 2 && cat foo

foo:
    @echo '$@' > $@
else
.NOTPARALLEL:

%:
    @$(MAKE) $@
endif
```

Of course, the condition of the conditional could be more sophisticated, like, for instance, testing if one of the goals matches `clean`...